# Convert my sites Primary Site Collection Administrators to ADFS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, adfs, mysites

We converted our SharePoint 2013 environment to ADFS. I forgot to copy the prod versions of the my sites content DBs to the staging before the conversion. I was able to get the DBs copied over via this post here:

[stack post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/233410/refresh-my-sites-dbs-in-uat-that-was-converted-to-adfs)

However, when I access the site collections in Central Admin, they have the NTLM user account as the Primary Site Collection Administrators instead of the ADFS account. When I try to access the my site url, I get "user not found". When I update the Primary Site Collection Administrators to the ADFS account, I can access the my site.

My question is, how to I change the primary site collection admins in central admin to the ADFS account without having to manually do each one? We have thousands. I have already converted the UPA to pull in the ADFS accounts and migrated all the users in the standard site collection to ADFS. I don't know if copying the my site DBs over after the conversion is the issue or if I am missing a step.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `Convert-SPWebApplication` to convert from Windows Claims to SAML Claims, or you can use `Move-SPUser`. `Convert-SPWebApplication` is probably the best route.

[Migration of Windows claims authentication to SAML-based claims authentication in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn744263.aspx)

Comment: I tried Convert-SPWebApplication and got errors. With the provider enabled: Convert-SPWebApplication : SAML based claim authentication is not compatible. With the provider disabled: Convert-SPWebApplication : There exists a zone with claims windows authentication enabled without SAML auth so we can't migrate safely. Maybe I'll have to look into Move-SPUser

Comment: You should fix the issue prior to performing any action. That error isn't any less applicable because of the route you plan on converting users from Windows Claims to SAML.

Comment: Dang, already did the Move-SPUser and it worked, but I see what your saying. Ugh. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: So I have one more question. Does Convert-SPWebApplication basically handle everything in one nice command, instead of running a script to move the users individually? It also sounds like you can create a skip list to ignore service accounts.

Comment: Yes, it has some other logic to also make the process faster and a few more checks than `Move-SPUser`.

Comment: I found out why I couldn't use Convert-SPWebApplication.  I found it here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3042604/the-convert-spwebapplication-command-cannot-convert-from-windows-claim I also found that after you create the trusted provider, you have to enable it on the web app before converting. I just might scrap my environment and start from scratch.

Comment: One more comment. I completely refreshed the environment and started over from scratch. Convert-SPWebApplication work perfectly and was so much faster. I like that it adds to the ULS for problem account migrations and how it handles the whole thing for you. It only took about ten minutes to do SP and My Sites. That was awesome. It also turned 100+ lines of user migration code into a 1 liner. Thanks again Trevor!

Answer (score 1):

You can run the move-spuser against all users, [here is nice script which will](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2014/09/03/how-to-migrate-sharepoint-users-to-adfs/) get the users from web application then convert them as required claims.
(please test it first before directly applying to prod).

```
$groupprefix = "c:0-.t|awesome adfs|"

$userprefix = "i:05.t|awesome adfs|"

$usersuffix = "@awesomespaceships.com"

# Get all of the users in a web application

$users = Get-SPUser -web "https://sfb-sp15-wfe1:8080/"

# Loop through each of the users in the web app

foreach($user in $users)

{

# Create an array that will be used to split the user name

$a=@()

$userlogin = $user.UserLogin

$username = “”

if($userlogin.Contains("i:")) # for users

{

$a = $userlogin.split('\')

$username = $userprefix + $a[1] + $usersuffix

}

elseif($userlogin.Contains("c:")) # for groups

{

$a = $displayname.split('\')

$username = $groupprefix + $a[1]

}

if ($userName -Like ("*" + [Environment]::UserName +"*")) {

Write-Host "Skipping this user '$user' so as to not loose SPA full-control rights..."

}

else{

if ($userName -ne '') {

Write-Host "Moving '$user' to '$username'..."

Move-SPUser –Identity $user –NewAlias $username -ignoresid -Confirm:$false

}

}

}
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Afraid I might have jumped the gun per Trevor's comments. Luckily this is only our staging environment.

Comment: thats ok,over here we suggest the stuff but you have to test and pick one which is suitable for your environment. thats why we recommend test it before applying to production.

Comment: right. I am finding converting to ADFS is no small matter. I may even perform the whole thing multiple times in staging until I am confident I can do this in my sleep. Thanks.